# Azure Functions - Visual Studio Tools

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I was trying to create Azure Functions as provided in the help link - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/12/01/visual-studio-tools-for-azure-functions/

I am actually creating a Evenhub trigger to write the messages to blob storage.

When I try to run the project, I am getting an error:

> "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
>   'Functions.DashPOCEventHub'. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Value
>   cannot be null."

I have put the correct values in the appsettings.json.

Can somebody help me with this error?

Also, when I try to publish the function to Azure, the appsettings.json is not being set correctly. I cannot see the values and keys when I go into the Azure UI application settings page.

Comment: Can you get it to run locally?

Answer (score 2):

`appsettings.json` won't create/override your web app ApplicationSettings when you deploy. You'll need to specify the ApplicationSettings for the web app [explicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure#application-settings).

The reason for this is so that you can use different secrets locally (`appsettings.json`) from what you deploy (web app appsettings).

There is more info on `appsettings.json` and web app Application Settings [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/12/01/visual-studio-tools-for-azure-functions/).

Comment: So it will create them if they don't exist and won't override if they exist?

Comment: No, deployment does nothing with appsettings.json. They are local development settings only.

Add the application settings directly to your web app (AzureWebJobsStorage, AzureWebJobsDashboard, etc) that you need.

Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Silly John, did you update the Azure CLI when you run your Function Locally? Today is on the **Azure Functions Console CLI 1.0.0-beta.97**.

Probably, this update solves this issue.